# lib curl symbol not found

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, libcurl

Really stupid C question.

I'm trying to build the source code here so I can start on modifying it for myself

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html

I download the file, then run

```
gcc -o test ftpget.c
```

and get

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_curl_global_init", referenced from:
      _main in ccFchguB.o
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      _main in ccFchguB.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _main in ccFchguB.o
      _main in ccFchguB.o
      _main in ccFchguB.o
      _main in ccFchguB.o
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in ccFchguB.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _main in ccFchguB.o
  "_curl_global_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in ccFchguB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

which makes no sense to me, because

```
/usr/local/include/curl/curl.h
```

exists and has these functions.  I'm sure this is some basic c compilation thing I'm missing.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to link with the curl library:

```
gcc -o test ftpget.c -lcurl
```

Comment: Can you explain please that why linking to lcurl is needed in this case?

Comment: @Ritesh `curl.h` is included during `pre-processing` time, which your compiler only grabs the declaration in the header file, but no definitions. If you don't link the libraries (mostly the binary object that contains definitions in that library), you will receive the `undefined symbols` error from your compiler.